# Adding directory path to a log file name

Tags: bash, path

Am writing  script using bash.

I have a name for a log file `log` and want to prepend a directory path `$destin`.  But `$destin` can either end with `/` or without `/`.

```
log="$destin/$log"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's variable expansions that do exactly that:

```
log="${destin%/}/$log"
```

The `%` removes the suffix that follows from the variable, if present.

However, this isn't ncecessary: `path//file" and "path/file" are the same file.

As Quasimodo points out:

If removing any number of slashes is really needed, `log="$(dirname "$destin")/$(basename "$destin")"` should do. This will also work if `destin` is something like `a/b/c///`.

Comment: You're right about `path//file` and `path/file`. Just be careful about removing all double slashes though, as [POSIX allows](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_271) for `//path/file` and `/path/file` to be different (a leading double slash is defined to be [implementation dependent](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_13))