# Making log file from last directory name

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, path

I have two directory paths `source` and `destin`.  Would like to construct a file name `logfl` with its path being that at destination `destin`, and its name being tho name of the last directory name.

- Example input data

  ```bsh
  source="/home/hagbard/01cuneus"
  destin="/media/hc1"
  ```
- Desired result for `logfl` would be:

  ```
  /media/hc1/01cuneus.log
  ```

Made the following attempt, but the filename is not being constructed properly:

```bsh
# set log file from name of last directory of SOURCE 
log="${source%/}"       # remove `/` if it occurs as last character
log="${source##*/}"     # gets last directory name from SOURCE
log="${destin%/}/$log"  # not absolutely necessary
```

Comment: You already have the answer to that in my answer to your previous question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/658911/adding-directory-path-to-a-log-file-name ; try to understand what `dirname` does.

Comment: Have resolved the problem by using `logfl="${logfl##*/}"`.  A small mistake.

Comment: Using `dirname` command with the absolute path of a directory will give the directory path, but I want the last directory name in path specified by `source`.

Comment: I assume the shell used is still `bash`?

Comment: @pietru, what happens when you `dirname $(dirname "${source}")`

Comment: Suppose I use `source="/home/hagbard/01cunues/"` then `test=$(dirname ${source}); test=$(dirname ${test});  echo "test: $test"` gives `test: /home`.  But I am looking to get `01cunues`.